# Best way to go from tuple pairs of numbers to one tuple of all the individual numbers

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can i get this

```
nums = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]
```

to this? The second item of each tuple is the first item of the next tuple.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I did:

```
>>> zip(*nums)[0]
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

But it gives me everything except the last element and then i had to use some bad code to get it to the correct result so i was looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: What's the general rule behind this? A list of pairs of which every second item equals the first item of the next?

Comment: For example, why don't you just do `range(nums[0][0], nums[-1][-1])`?

Comment: Yeah, that's why i was wandering about a good way to get all the individual numbers eg after doing `zip(x,x[1:])` for example.

Comment: Is it always a consecutive sequence of numbers?

Comment: I don't just do that because I wanted to know the Python way to get all the elements out of curiosity, no practical use.

Comment: I'm just asking because it's not clear what you want to get as a general rule, for example if the input is `[(0,2),(2,5),(5,10)]` or even `[(1,2),(3,4)]`. The `zip(x, x[1:])` comment makes this clear, so you should add it to the question.

Comment: Does it matter if it is consecutive or not?

Comment: Yes, because if the numbers are consecutive, it's as simple as `range(nums[0][0], nums[-1][-1] + 1)`.

Comment: Ok so i will add that to the question. I wasn't looking for range, wanted to get the items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what your general case is, but

```
[nums[0][0]] + [x[1] for x in nums]
```

For your example

```
range(nums[-1][-1] + 1)
```

also works, can you describe what you are trying to do rather than just giving one simple case?

Comment: I think you mean `[nums[0][0]] + ...`?

Comment: This is enough, i just thought of the case myself, didn't have anything i was trying to do thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> nums = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]
>>> i = iter(nums)
>>> next(i) + tuple(y for x,y in i)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

More efficient version using `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> nums = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]
>>> i = iter(nums)
>>> list(chain(next(i),(y for x,y in i)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: You seem to be recreating `tuple` object 2 times: first `tuple(y for x,y in i)` is constructed, and then `next(i) + tuple(y for x,y in i)` is constructed (because `tuple` is immutable).

Comment: It may be workarounded this way: `tuple(itertools.chain(i.next(),(y for x,y in i)))`

Comment: Good point, i'll change it to use chain, i had that originally but i thought it was simpler to just add two tuples but i agree it is bad practice.

Comment: @ovgolovin: So what? Are we talking about efficiency here? I think this a perfectly valid and readable way, `itertools` would make it unnecessarily complex. By the way, list addition (like in gnibbler's solution) poses the exact same "problem", so this has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: I agree with @NiklasB. here. jamylak, you should include both methods for completeness. The tuple-adding version is elegant, and (in any case) is as good as gnibbler's list-adding version.

Comment: Ok i'll include both methods.

Comment: @NiklasB Just wondering though, you said gnibblers solution has the exact same problem but i assumed that lists would add faster than tuples. Is this not the case?

Comment: @jamylak: No, why should it be that way? both are implemented as arrays.

Comment: @NiklasB I just slipped in this remark about `itertools.chain` for it to be here in the comments to accompany the answer (maybe someone reading this answer will learn something new). I think the choose of the variant of implementation depends on what it going to be achieved (and in the most of the cases summing up the tuples will be preferred (because of the better readability of the code)).

Comment: @ovgolovin: If you want it to be read, you could just as well add it to the accepted answer ;)

Comment: @NiklasB. I think that in the gnibber's answer the first `list` may be `extend`ed `[nums[0][0]].extend([x[1] for x in nums])` (thought it wouldn't be readable at all, as `extend` returns `None` and some additional code would be needed to address it; and furthermore `extend` in fact would probably make some additional memory allocations).

Comment: @NiklasB If I'm interested in the question, I read all the answers and all the comments (because usually they make the whole picture more complete: answers sometimes give different points of views).

Comment: @ovgolovin: That is of course true. Just wanted to point out that list concatenation is no more efficient than tuple concatenation. In both cases, the whole contents have to be copied over. The only data structure where this particular operation would be cheap is an immutable, singly linked list.

Comment: @NiklasB I commented in this answer because I liked a solution by jamylak. I like the usage of `next(i)` and the following `(y for x,y in i)`. Just decided to add something which I thought might be relevant. It's no way that I somehow tried to fault the fist solution by jamylak :)

Comment: Both solutions are fine, i wasn't sure myself which one to use so its fine now that they are both are there, should have done that in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def flatten(E):
    if E in [[], ()]:
        return []
    elif type(E) not in [list, tuple]:
        return [E]
    else:
        return flatten(E[0]) + flatten(E[1:])

def declutter(L):
    s = set()
    answer = []
    for i in L:
        if i not in s:
            s.add(i)
            answer.append(i)
    return answer

>>> nums = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]
>>> declutter(flatten(nums))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can use an `OrderedHash` for `declutter` and `[x for a in lst for b in a]` for `flatten`, if you really want to go this way. This is a bit verbose for Python, IMHO (and it's invalid as well, indentation is meaningful in Python).

Comment: Thank you Niklas. I had copied the code from my text editor, improperly as it seems. Thanks for correcting the indentation